# How to make the distance between nodes depend on the value in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am using the following code and example here to make a force directed graph: https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8

(both code and json input file are provided in the above link)

I would like this graph to result in a clustering of similar nodes based on the **value** of the json data. At the moment, this value determines the width of the links, rather than the distance between nodes.

In the example by [heybignick](https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8), the distances are defined as shown below. How can I **exactly** adapt this so that the distance between each node depends on the value between source and target ?

segment of javascript code from heybignick:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))//.distance(function(d,i){return 1*i}))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
```

fyi: I am inexperienced with javascript

Comment: All nodes? Or just nodes with links? Would an individual link length be a function of both nodes it connects, or just one of those nodes?

Comment: Nodes with links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.distance` method of link forces.

From [the documentation:](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_distance)

> link.distance([distance])
> If distance is specified, sets the distance accessor to the specified number or function, re-evaluates the distance accessor for each link, and returns this force. If distance is not specified, returns the current distance accessor, which defaults to:

```js
function distance() {
  return 30;
}
```

> The distance accessor is invoked for each link, **being passed the link** and its zero-based index [...].

So, if the distance of a link between nodes depends on attributes in the source and target nodes, you can define:

```js
function distance(link) {
  return myDistanceFunction(link.source, link.target);
}
```

Where `myDistanceFunction` is responsible for taking the source and target nodes and converting them to a pixel distance. Then pass the `distance` function to the force:

```js
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(links)
    .id(d => d.id)
    .distance(distance)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the idea better. Since I don't know javascript, I was wondering where in the script should this function be placed ? I see that in the link I shared containing an example script, it has a couple of "var"'s and below 4 functions. I am unsure how to implement this in that example.